# Without using an explicit JOIN operator make multi table sub query in SQL?

Tags: sql, subquery, multi-table

Without using an explicit JOIN operator ind the Per Capita Income of the Community Area which has a school Safety Score of 1.

```sql
    SELECT per_capita_income,community_area_name
    FROM CENSUS_DATA
    where community_area_name =
        (SELECT community_area_name FROM CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS where safety_score='1' )
```

response is "per_capita_income" "community_area_name" 
there is no value??? 
Thanks everyone for all response below but the result did not changed, there is no value, however i tried:

```sql
 SELECT community_area_name FROM CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS 
where safety_score='1'
```

and get the result as 'WASHINGTON PARK' and did seqond query as

```sql
SELECT per_capita_income,community_area_name FROM CENSUS_DATA 
where community_area_name = 'WASHINGTON PARK'
```

I've got again;
`per_capita_income    community_area_name`

I've checked below code to confirm and get all per_capita_income values inc. Washington Park

```
SELECT per_capita_income,community_area_name FROM CENSUS_DATA
```

so,finally  I could not get the capita_income value.
The data is in the below links

CENSUS_DATA:

https://ibm.box.com/shared/static/05c3415cbfbtfnr2fx4atenb2sd361ze.csv

CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS

https://ibm.box.com/shared/static/f9gjvj1gjmxxzycdhplzt01qtz0s7ew7.csv

CHICAGO_CRIME_DATA:

https://ibm.box.com/shared/static/svflyugsr9zbqy5bmowgswqemfpm1x7f.csv

Comment: Please execute `SELECT community_area_name FROM CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS where safety_score='1'` then pick the result and execute `SELECT per_capita_income,community_area_name
FROM CENSUS_DATA
where community_area_name = '<your result>'` and add the information to your question.  BTW you probably want to replace the `=` operator by a `IN` operator.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not using a `JOIN` makes this a homework/quiz question, not a *practical* programming problem.

Comment: Thanks everyone,I think I solved  , when I query small caps as below it worked:
 ``` 
SELECT per_capita_income,community_area_name FROM CENSUS_DATA where community_area_name= 'Washington Park' ```
 I think I is not equal i in my language settings...

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE CENSUS_DATA SET COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME = UPPER(COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME)  
select  CD.PER_CAPITA_INCOME  
from CENSUS_DATA CD,CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS CPS 
where CD.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME = CPS.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME 
and CPS.SAFETY_SCORE = 1
```

The CENSUS_DATA COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME column has values in lower case and for the CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME column they are in upper case so it's better to update the particular column using UPDATE operation and perform query operation to get the required answer

Comment: You should provide a brief explanation of why this works.

Comment: Please _edit the answer_ you provided rather than using a comment to elaborate and clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

try this one :

```
SELECT c.per_capita_income, c.community_area_name
    FROM CENSUS_DATA c, CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS s 
    WHERE s.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER  = c.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER AND s.SAFETY_SCORE = '1' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you’re looking for an implicit join like this:

```
SELECT cd.per_capita_income,cd.community_area_name
FROM CENSUS_DATA as cd, CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS as cps
where cd.community_area_name = cps.community_area_name 
AND cps.safety_score='1'
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @lau, it is likely that the problem that you are seeing comes from your data.

However, let me also point out that there is an lurking issue with this condition :

```
WHERE community_area_name =
    (SELECT community_area_name FROM CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS where safety_score='1' )
```

If more than one one record in `CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS` exists with safety score equal to 1, the equality condition will not properly work (in most RDBMS this results in a runtime error).

This condition should rewritten, either as an `IN` condition :

```
SELECT per_capita_income,community_area_name
FROM CENSUS_DATA
WHERE community_area_name IN
    (SELECT community_area_name FROM CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS where safety_score='1' )
```

Or as a correlated subquery with an `EXIST` condition :

```
SELECT c.per_capita_income, c.community_area_name
FROM CENSUS_DATA c
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS s
    WHERE s.community_area_name  = c.community_area_name AND s.safety_score = '1' 
)
```

Comment: Yea, I commented on that too

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at the data and as everyone expected, I can confirm there is a problem with your data.

`COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME` is uppercase in CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOL
It is propercase in CENSUS_DATA.

A string that is lowercase is always **different** than a string that is UPPERCASE and they are both different from a string that is Propercase.

The correct solution is probably to review your database design and put a foreign key somewhere. We do not have enough details to help on such a thing.

The **less** correct set everything to propercase for instance and re-run the corrected `SELECT`.

```
UPDATE CENSUS_DATA SET community_area_name = INITCAP(community_area_name);
UPDATE CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS  SET community_area_name = INITCAP(community_area_name);


SELECT per_capita_income,community_area_name
    FROM CENSUS_DATA
    where community_area_name IN
        (SELECT community_area_name FROM CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS where safety_score='1' )
```

Comment: It depends on the database settings, if it’s ci (case-insensitive) there will be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT per_capita_income FROM CENSUS_DATA WHERE upper(community_area_name) IN 
(SELECT "Community_Area_Name" FROM CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS WHERE "Safety_Score" = 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

when are your answer should not contain any join you must use cross product for example if you have 2 tables you must use `select * from table1,table2 where condition`

in your case, the answer should be

```
select PER_CAPITA_INCOME from school S,cencus_data C where C.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME = S.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME and S.SAFETY_SCORE=1
```

if it not works change with any other common column between these 2 tables

I hope it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```sql
select PER_CAPITA_INCOME from CENSUS_DATA 
where UPPER(COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME) = (
    select COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME from CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS where SAFETY_SCORE = 1
);
```

Option 2:

```sql
select PER_CAPITA_INCOME from CENSUS_DATA 
where UPPER(COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME) in (
    select COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME from CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS where SAFETY_SCORE = 1
)
```

Either should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing the "Databases and SQL for Data Science" course on Coursera. The problem is in the datasets. If you take a look in the census data csv the community name is on lower case, while in the schools csv is on upper case. So this should do the trick

%sql SELECT COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME, PER_CAPITA_INCOME \
FROM CENSUS_DATA \
WHERE UCASE(COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME) = (SELECT "Community_Area_Name" FROM CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS WHERE "Safety_Score" = 1)

Answer (score 0):

%sql select community_area_name, per_capita_income from census_data where community_area_name='Washington Park';

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```sql
%%sql 
select CPS.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME, CD.PER_CAPITA_INCOME, CPS.SAFETY_SCORE
    from CENSUS_DATA CD, CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS CPS
where CD.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER = CPS.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER 
    and SAFETY_SCORE = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is community_area_name in Chicago schools is Upper case while in Census data is lower case
so this code worked with me ,,

%sql select per_capita_income,community_area_number,community_area_name from CENUS_DATA where community_area_number in (select community_area_number from SCHOOLS where safety_score=1)

Comment: Please consider adding code formatting to your answer. In edit click the {} button after selecting the part that is code

Answer (score -1):

```
%%sql select  per_capita_income from CENSUS
where community_area_number = (select community_area_number from SCHOOLS where safety_score = 1)
```

- remove the `'` from around `'1'`